# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name returning an object reference error

Tags: httpcontext, object-reference

I have a controller: AdminController in which is a method that has this declaration:

```
string user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
```

it gives me an object reference not set to an instance of an object error...

However, I have another controller (BatchesController) in which I do this:

```
Regex.Match(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, @"([^\\]+$)").Groups[0].Value
```

It works fine...

I also have another controller that uses it fine:

```
public class AuthoriseUser : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString().ToUpper();
            List<string> a = GetAll();
            Boolean authorise = false;

            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
            }

            IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                authorise = true;
            }
```

Sorry that is just a snippet. But it works.

Why is it that it fails in that one place? Please tell me if you need more context to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was creating a new AdminController object:

```
AdminController ac = new AdminController();
```

Instead I stored the user in a variable and passed it instead of using the 'user' variable.